# Returning a String Endless Times

Tags: python, spyder

```
command = input("> ")
started = False

while True:
if command == "start":
  if started:
   print("car has already started") 
  else: 
      started = True
      print("car started")
elif command == "stop":
    if not started:
        print("car has already stopped")
    else:
        started = False
        print("car is stopped")
elif command == "quit":
    break
```

it renders "car has already started" infinite time when i state "start" and likewise with other inputs. how do i inhibit this? would be very helpful if you explain it in beginner terms, thank you!!

Comment: fetch the command inside of the while loop, (you never get chance to get more inputs from the user so they can stop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Male sure to add the input to thie while loop. In your case, it is just taking one input and then the value of `command` is fixed. So, it is an infinite loop.

But when you change the location and keep it inside the loop, every time it asks for the input, the value of `command` will change.

Also, `.lower()` will convert the input to lower case to remove case insensitivity

```
started = False

while True:
    command=input('>> ').lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("car has already started") 
        else: 
            started = True
            print("car started")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("car has already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print("car is stopped")
    elif command == "quit":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the command inside the while loop, so that the loop stops until the user has enterd his desired command:

```
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ")
    if command == "start":
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need input a new command every while loop, otherwise it will fall into infinite loop with the same first inputed command condiction.

code:

```
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ")
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("car has already started") 
        else: 
            started = True
            print("car started")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("car has already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print("car is stopped")
    elif command == "quit":
        break
```

result:

```
> start
car started
> stop
car is stopped
> stop
car has already stopped
> start
car started
> start
car has already started
> quit
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in your loop is:

1. `while True` - A while loop will always run until this statement is `False`, as True is never False, this will loop forever until the break command is ran.
2. `if command == "start"` - Because `command` is set outside of the while loop, it is always equal to `start` and this if statement will always run
3. The first run, it will print "car started" and every other loop after will print "car has already started".

To stop this, you need to change the value of `command` to change the behaviour each time you loop. To do this, you can just get an input at the start of the loop:

```
started = False

while True:
    command = input("> ") # Input inside the loop
    if command == "start":
      if started:
       print("car has already started") 
      else: 
          started = True
          print("car started")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("car has already stopped")
        else:
            started = False
            print("car is stopped")
    elif command == "quit":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value for command and the loop is running "while True", so it will never stop.

When the user gives the input, lets say "start", your script is assigning the string "start" to the command.

It is looping infinitely because the first if statement is checking the value for the variable command, which after the input will always be "start".

You can solve it in multiple ways.
One is to change the name of the variable after the if statement:

command = input("> ")
started = False

```
while True:
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("car has already started")
            command = ""
```

Another way is to add break commands after each if comparison.

You can also change `while True` to `while not started`. The loop will continue until you change the variable `started` to True, which you are already doing after each conditional block.